# In PowerShell how do I remove a duplicate item from a split path without changing the order?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove duplicates from the Windows environment system path.  It seems like the only way to do this is to split the path by semicolon and use sort-object with the -unique parameter or pipe to get-unique.  However, it changes the sort order completely after that, and I want it to be the same order it was from the beginning, just minus the duplicates.

```
$RegPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
$hklm = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine
$RegKey = $hklm.OpenSubKey($regPath, $FALSE)
$OldPath = $regKey.GetValue("Path", "", [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames)
$SplitPath = $OldPath -split ';'
$NoDupesPath = ($SplitPath | Sort-Object | Get-Unique) -join ';'
```

I want $NoDupesPath to be the same order as $OldPath, minus the duplicates, but that's not happening when using Sort-Object.  I also don't want any semicolons to show up at the very beginning or end of $NoDupesPath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object -Unique` to get a unique collection and keep the order of the first occurrence of each item.

```
PS> $OldPath = "foo;bar;foo;baz;foo;bar;qux;baz;bar"
PS> $NoDupesPath = ($OldPath -split ';' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ';'
PS> $NoDupesPath
foo;bar;baz;qux
```

Comment: All of these were great answers but I like this one the best.  Also, because I didn't want any semicolons at the beginning or end I modified it some.  $NoDupesPath = (($OldPath -split ';' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ';').Trim(';').TrimEnd(';')

Comment: @Chris - have you run the code _without_ the `.Trim()` calls? the `-join` operator is not supposed to add leading or trailing items - only "between".

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Not that exact command line, but previously when using the -join operator I would sometimes see a ; at the very end.  The command I was using previously was `$NoDupesPath = ($SplitPath | Sort-Object -Unique -Descending) -join ';'`

Comment: @Chris - thank you for the added info. [*grin*] if you are getting leading or trailing "join" chars, then you have a leading/trailing blank/whitespace item. i would check up on that ...

Answer (score 3):

Inspire from this snippet I just threw together.

```
$s = 'a;b;c;b;b;a;a'

$a = $s -split ';'

$h = [ordered]@{}

# could use any value, or +1 to see count
$a | % {$h[$_] = $h[$_]+1}

"our hash table"
$h

"keys is unique and in order"
$h.Keys

$uniqueSameOrder = $h.Keys -join ';'

"uniqueSameOrder"
$uniqueSameOrder
```

Comment: +1 for providing all the crucial pointers, but, frankly, it's not that obvious how to translate them into a working solution.
Encouraging askers to understand the underlying concepts is commendable, but I feel that this is best accomplished by _annotating_ a _working solution_.

Comment: Point taken @mklement0.  I always try to balance the teaching part, allowing OPs to learn on their own, versus code writing and then OPs never learn the concepts if they just cut/paste everything. (general answer here, not necessarily this OP!)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, eliminating duplicates with `Get-Unique` (or, more directly, with `Sort-Object -Unique`) requires *sorting* the elements, which contradicts your requirements.

**Update**: [Don Cruickshank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374659/45375) offers the simplest solution; conceptually speaking, the solution below is a manual (and therefore unnecessary) re-implementation of `Select-Object -Unique`.

---

[Kory Gill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373374/45375) contains all the ingredients for a solution; here's the full recipe:

```
$NoDupesPath = $OldPath -split ';' | ForEach-Object `
  -Begin   { $oht = [ordered] @{} } `
  -Process { $oht[$_] = $true } `
  -End     { $oht.Keys -join ';' }
```

Due to pipeline use, this won't be the fastest solution, but it's concise and (hopefully) conceptually clear:

- At the *start* of processing (the `-Begin` block) , `$oht = [ordered] @{}` creates an empty *ordered* hashtable (a hashtable whose keys reflect the order in which keys (entries) are created; PSv3+)
- For *each* input path (the `-Process` block), `if ($oht[$_]) { return }` is a no-op if the input path at hand is already in the ordered hashtable, thereby skipping duplicates.
- `$oht[$_] = $true` creates a hashtable entry for a path not previously seen; for a duplicate, the existing entry is simply *updated*, which amounts to a *no-op*, causing duplicates to be effectively *ignored*; after all paths have been processed, `$oht.Keys` therefore contains only *unique* paths, in *input order*.
- At the *end* of processing (the `-End` block), `$oht.Keys -join ';'` outputs the unique paths - in input order - joined to form a single string with separator `;`.

Answer (score 2):

here's a solution that uses `Group-Object`. [*grin*] one thing that is not always apparent is that the resulting groups are *in the order they are detected*. that means you automatically get the original sequence in this situation ...

```
$OriSequence = 'a;f;c;b;b;f;a;a;c;s;r;v;q'

$SplitSequence = $OriSequence.Split(';')
$UniqueSequence =  ($SplitSequence |
    Group-Object).Name -join ';'

$OriSequence
$UniqueSequence
```

output ...

```
a;f;c;b;b;f;a;a;c;s;r;v;q
a;f;c;b;s;r;v;q
```

Comment: Good side effect of Grouping to remember.

Comment: @KoryGill - i was delighted when i 1st noticed it. that allowed me to remove a bunch of code ... [*grin*]

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `(('a','f','c','b','b','f','a','a','c','s','r','v','q') | Select-Object -Unique ) -join ','` actually do the same?

Comment: @Olaf - pro'ly. [*blush*] when i 1st started using PoSh the `-Unique` would only work if you sorted the list 1st. that has been fixed, so you are likely quite correct - but i have not tested that.